# wifi connection down intermittently (only with WPA2)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

At home I have a wi-fi connection. I usually connect to wi-fi with my Windows7 laptop. The connection is good because I'm not so far from router; it is also an open connection, that is it is nor WEP or WPA.
I've decided, then, to add a WPA2 key into the router for my wireless connection. After that, I've noticed that my connection on laptop goes down intermittently. I have other devices that I used with wi-fi connection and noone has connection problems...I've this behaviour only on my Windows7 pc laptop...
Anybody can help me?

EDIT:
My router is DLink DSL-2640R (but I don't think that it is a router problem because other devices works well with this configuration). I've set up also the automatic channel scan for wireless and only 802.11g (it does not made for .11n). On my pc I have the Atheros AR9285 wireless adapter

Comment: Have you tried switching the broadcast to a different channel while using WPA2?

Comment: I'm going to do it and I will notice you...please give an answer and I will give feedback there

Comment: I've tried to  give an automatic search of channel. Router automatically choose 11, but it does not work: it seems that connection goes down when I try to load some new webpage...

Comment: You didn't give much info about what equipment/settings you use. If you're on `802.11n` with the laptop you could setting it to `802.11g`. What is the "link"-speed you're getting?

Comment: What do you mean with equipment and settings?I can say that my router supports only 802.11g and b.

Comment: With equipment i meant what brand/type/firmware of router (maybe the router has a faulty WPA2 implementation). Did you check for latest firmware of the router? With settings i meant the 11g or 11n, WPA2 EAS or TKIP coding. You could try setting 11g only (and not mixed). You can also try setting WEP to see if it helps any. If only your laptop has a problem what kind of WiFi-adapter is it? Did you check for the latest drivers for it, not only on the Microsoft site but also with the manufacturer. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Did you get a good "link-speed" of 54Mbps? You can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/678987/edit) your answers in your original question.

Comment: What was your link-speed? and did you try WPA (not WPA2) or WEP? Firmware of the DSL-2640R? Even if other devices don't have problems it could still be the interaction between the router and your card at WPA2 level (hence the suggestion to try WPA or WEP). When the link goes down for your laptop, do the other devices still have access to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had to install a BT Homehub 4 for my parents and one of the laptops in their house refused to connect. It was simply down to the wireless encryption format being too "new" for the hardware. Windows recognised it with no issues but refused the connection.

Once the connection was established with WEP everything was fine again albeit a little slower.

Comment: with WEP everything works well. I will see about issues of my wireless adapter with WPA2

Comment: It's odd how new can be baffled by old